# How to query the count of two fields by two different clauses at the same time?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I want to query for a count of a WHERE clause 1 and another count of WHERE clause 2. I have a simplified query result for my booking app:

```
Token   Pending    OverDue
---------------------------------
ITB001    1          23
IASFSA    8          4
WERSFD    7          1
XVCSFD    2          11
RERSDF    2          7
XVCLKD    1          8
MKB114    1          11
```

I want to 3 columns in total, first being a field called `Token`, second the count of `Pending` grouped by `renter`, and finally the count `Overdue` field grouped also by `renter`.

For the queries for `Token` and the count of `Pending`, I set the clause for any items that has an `endDate`(a.k.a due date) later than today's date by 1 day:

```sql
SELECT token, COUNT(renter) FROM booking WHERE endDate >= CAST (current_date + 1 AS timestamp) AND endDate <  CAST (current_date + 2 AS timestamp) GROUP BY renter, token
```

The second column would be a similar query, but the `endDate` later than today's date by 1 day. How do I query the count of `Pending` and `Overdue` group by `renter` at the same time?

Comment: What is *renter*? I don't see this column in your sample data.

Comment: `renter` is one of the fields from the database that is unique. You don't see it in the table because I don't need that to be retrieved. I only want it to be used to group the query results by.  Think of the `renter` as a unique serial number

Comment: This is unclear. You define *both* columns as the the count of rentres that have endDate *later than today's date by 1 day*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT token, COUNT(*),
       SUM(CASE WHEN enddate = current_date + interval '1 day' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM booking 
GROUP BY token;
```

You have inconsistent database tags, but I've used a Postgres-like syntax for the date operations.

Comment: thank you. I'm using `node-postgres` so that might explain it